# Calling a template file in a static block

Tags: magento

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template') ->setTemplate('postcode/postcode.phtml')->toHtml()`

I want to call this code in a static block. How to do this?

Comment: i am using "Logistic Features Availability Estimator for Pin Codes " Magento extension. They have given the php code to write in phtml .. But i want to call that extension in a static block rather in phtml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call a phtml file from CMS Page or CMS Block then paste the following code in content area.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="postcode/postcode.phtml"}}
```

Comment: the pincode extension is getting displayed that i am calling in a static block in a widget but not working. why??

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the block type, block id and the template path to suit your exact requirements.

Something like:

```
{{block type="core/template" block_id="demo.block" template="your/template/path.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new static block in backend, eg, `new-static-block.`

Open the static block and put code like this to assign a template to it.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newtemplatefile.phtml"}}
```

Call the static block through code, or in xml (preferred way)